# Имитатор рабочего стола Windows

Tags: windows, visual-c++

По заданию нужно написать имитатор рабочего стола Windows, с возможностью создавать ярлыки, просмотреть информацию о файле/папке, создавать/удалять/переименовывать файлы, упорядочивать файлы и т.п. Подскажите в какую сторону копать. Все это нужно написать с использованием Visual C++ или Borland C++.

Comment: Чтобы подсказать в какую сторону копать, нужно знать что вы уже знаете. C/C++, VisualStudio, WinAPI осваивайте.

Comment: Чтобы что-то осваивать нужно знать в какую сторону двигаться, а то так можно освоить то, что совершенно не нужно для данной задачи. Вот в WinAPI есть функция OpenDesktop, но вот как отобразить после этого рабочий стол в окне своей программы я не понимаю.

Comment: Осваивайте язык, если WinAPI для вас не подходит.

Comment: Я не сказал что WinAPI не подходит, я говорил что тот же WinAPI  можно осваивать, например, в части мультимедиа, хотя для решения этой задачи это не нужно. Мне нужно хотя бы узнать какие разделы смотреть.